# IBM DB2: how to change a view's structure without deleting it and create it again?

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

IBM DB2: how to change a view's structure without deleting it and create it again?
"
I have a view in DB2 IBM i-series and I would need to "update"/change it's "query". The only way I know so far is deleting and building it again but in this case I have another view based on this one and if I delete the first one, the second is deleted to..

Answer (score 4):

If you are running on i5/OS V7.1, then you can use `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`.

If not, then (unfortunately) you will have to drop / recreate the view (and its dependent objects).

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE seems to be doing what i need, but we are still stuck on Version 8 for some time :(

Comment: http://www.iprodeveloper.com/article/databasesql/sql-create-replace-improve-db2-object-management-699310

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for the [alter view](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref/raview.htm) syntax?

Comment: Posting syntax for DB2 on z/OS is not useful when the OP mentions that he is running on iSeries.

Comment: I am not sure how this answer helped the OP. I have the same question and the linked page does not answer it.

Answer (score -1):

you would have to see which other views are using this view
and would have to recreate them. 
you can use this command:
DSPDBR